# App Maker Exporting a useful output from Doc Approval Template

Tags: google-app-maker

I've used (and customised) an app from the Document Approval Template. I have also found the basic way to export the entered records to google sheets.

They come out as separate sheets, showing all the documents / approvers etc as a list on separate sheets, but what I really need is something that shows the relations i.e. who it was that auth each submitted record (especially with some making use of the two step auth feature of the template)

Any ideas?

Comment: To my understanding Google supposedly is working (is going to be working) on including import/export of related records in the built in import and export function, however I am not aware of a timeline for this. Right now the only option would be a custom server script to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to announce that App Maker supports [associations import/export](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/release-notes#import_and_export_relations) now.