# how to add relations for imported data besides server-side scripting in Google App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

My company has lots of data in Google Sheets which is nowadays too slow to work with so I built an app and data models with relations to handle the tasks. Next I need to import the data but **is there any way to map the data relations while importing from Google Sheets?**

The only way I could come up with is to write a server-side script but considering that App Maker is a platform for non-developers I think there could be some build-in way for this..? And thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: As user Marcus Malessa comments in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767048/app-maker-exporting-a-useful-output-from-doc-approval-template) (citation needed of course),  " Google supposedly is working (is going to be working) on including import/export of related records in the built in import and export function, however I am not aware of a timeline for this. Right now the only option would be a custom server script to accomplish this"

Comment: @nbryans Thanks for your comment and it's just as I expected. I already did it with client-side script. :)

Comment: @nbryans The topic of import/export of relation data was discussed in this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appmaker-users/BMVVCZmBPuw in the google app maker user group. Unfortunately there has been no further update on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

App Maker recently released first party support for Export and Import data with relations. You can find more details by following these links:

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/release-notes#import_and_export_relations

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export#what_you_can_expect_as_a_result

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export#what_you_can_expect_as_a_result_1